# Left join Vs Sub query Mysql

Tags: mysql, subquery, left-join

Sorry for bad english,

I have two querys like

1)

```
select t1.id,case when t2.p_id IS NULL then 'Text' ELSE (select t3.data from t3 where t3.p_id = t2.p_id) END FROM t1,t2
WHERE t2.id = t1.id
```

And another query

2)

```
select t1.id, t3.data 
FROM t1,t2 left join t3 on t3.p_id = t2.p_id WHERE t2.id = t1.id
```

which of the above two query is faster and why?

Thanks for giving time.

Comment: Use `explain select ...` to see the difference.

Comment: did you review the `explain` on both?

Comment: Joining on primary keys should be efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not read your queries in detail, but in general the structure of the second query is better.